# UserControl Inheritance WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, uwp

I wanted to implement a base class for my views. This class looks like the following:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<T> : UserControl, IView where T : ViewModelBase 
{
    protected ViewModelBase viewModel;

    public ViewBase(T viewModel) : base()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeComponent();

    public void OnViewCalled(object parameters)
    {
        this.viewModel.OnCalled(parameters);
    }
}
```

This is the usage of the base class:

```
public sealed partial class LoginView : ViewBase<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginView(LoginViewModel viewModel) : base(viewModel)
    { 
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try the above code, I get the following error:

> CS1729  C# 'UserControl' does not contain a constructor that takes 1
>   arguments

Why is not the constructor of the `ViewBase` class called?

Comment: I think you have to define the default constructor as well.

Comment: You've defined a partial class, presumably part of the class is defined in XAML? Did you also inherit from ViewBase in XAML or did you use UserControl?

Comment: i inherited from `UserControl`

Comment: In that case that's your immediate issue. I suspect you're going to run into further issues though. For one the auto generated code is going to make a public InitializeComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you inherited from `ViewBase` in code behind but `UserControl` in XAML.

**LoginView.xaml**

```
<Local.View:ViewBase x:Class="YourNameSpace.View.LoginView"
                     x:TypeArguments="Local.ViewModel:LoginViewModel"
                     xmlns:Local.View="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.View"
                     xmlns:Local.ViewModel="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.ViewModel">
</Local.View:ViewBase>
```

**LoginView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace YourNameSpace.View
{
    public partial class LoginView : ViewBase<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginView(LoginViewModel viewModel)
            : base(viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewBase.cs**

```
namespace YourNameSpace.View
{
    public abstract class ViewBase<T> : UserControl
        where T : ViewModelBase
    {
        protected ViewModelBase ViewModel;

        public ViewBase(T viewModel)
            : base()
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;
            DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work because it is a `abstract` base class and does not contain any default constructor but in general I don't want to change my code this way. is there any possibility to achieve that?

Comment: Your issue shouldn't be related to `abstract` and you don't need a parameterless constructor. It should work as provided but I think you'll have issues with InitializeComponent as mentioned previously.

Comment: i tried your code and, there is still an error because when the view code is generated it does not contain a generic type :/

Comment: Did you include the TypeArguments? The code above works, I made a new project and tested. The auto generated code inherits from ViewBase<LoginViewModel> same as the defined partial and XAML.

Comment: yes i included the TypeArguments, did you use a Windows Universal App?

Comment: okay i found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809644/usercontrol-inheritance-wpf/42810165?noredirect=1#comment72777150_42810165 thanks for your help!